# Cycle detection in graphs containing multiple cycles

Tags: graph, cycle, depth-first-search

I have the following graph:

[image: Sample graph shown by adenine molecule. Atoms are vertices, bonds are edges]

Is there a way I can identify all cycles in this graph? I know that DFS can be used to detect cycles by simply doing DFS until a back edge is found, but I was wondering if there is a computationally efficient way to return the individual cycles, considering that there are actually 3 cycles in the graph (1-2-3-4-5-6, 4-5-7-8-9, 1-2-3-4-9-8-7-5-6). I am a bit stuck because it seems like the carbon atom belongs to multiple graphs and I can't think of any way other than brute-forcing all possible paths originating from every vertex.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to find all pathes from EVERY vertex.

Only vertex refering to 3 or more other may belong to multiple cycles

You have to check only 4,5,6(,9)

Comment: wait, doesn't vertex 8 belong to 4-5-7-8-9 and 1-2-3-4-9-8-7-5-6?

Comment: vertex 8 belongs to both and you will find both cycles when checking all pathes from the nodes 4,5,6 (with duplicates)